# VSCode: Change text editor for an extension. E.g. open .txt with json editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode and want to know if it is possible to set an editor as default editor for a file extension.

Temporarily I am able to open the .txt with json editor by selecting the `JSON` from the bottom right corner of the vscode as shown in the screen shot

[image]

Is it possible to set it for default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a way to do it by appending `settings.json`

Open the file by going to `Preferences>>User Settings`

Just add the given below code in the file

```
{
    "files.associations": {
        "*.txt": "json"
    }
}
```

[image]